# Enough security to pass data from database

Tags: php, database, content-management-system

I wonder if my solution is enough secured.

Let's say I have a database with names and phone numbers of my clients and I have a CMS with one admin account.

In this CMS I need to show data ONLY TO LOGGED ADMIN, but I need to do it asynchronous (real-time, when some data comes new to database).

So I'm doing that by AJAX request which calls a php method that returns json with data without any encryption, BUT! only if the $_SESSION is set and `$_SESSION['admin']` is  = 1

is this enough to secure data from outside attackers ?

Comment: Not really the question to ask here i think. Secure, by my definition, is dependent on how well your code is written. Are you putting user inputted data directly into queries? Are you cleaning human input data of any html before serving it to the client?

Comment: I think using session if fine for denying access to some pages as the session is set serverside.